# CEdit selects everything when getting focus

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cedit

When I move to a CEdit control on my dialog using the tab key or the arrow keys all the text in the control is selected. This behaviour is causing me problems and I would prefer it if the control just put the cursor at the start (or end) of the text and didn't select anything.
Is there a simple way to do this (e.g. a property of the control that I can set)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that such a style exists.
But you can add OnSetfocus handler with the wizard:

```
void CMyDlg::OnSetfocusEdit1() 
{
  CEdit* e = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
  e->SetSel(0); // <-- hide selection
}
```

Comment: This did not quite work for me.  My edit control is multi-line and whose contents can be taller than the control (I have a vertical scroll bar).  The bNoScroll needs to be TRUE, and the selection for "no select" is -1, 0, so my code called it like `e->SetSel(-1, 0, TRUE);`.  This maintains any current scroll position as I tab through the controls of my dialog, but also ensures nothing is selected once focus returns back to my edit control.

Answer (score 8):

Another way of achieving your goal is to prevent the contents from being selected. When navigating over controls in a dialog the dialog manager queries the respective controls about certain properties pertaining to their behavior. By default an edit control responds with a `DLGC_HASSETSEL` flag (among others) to indicate to the dialog manager that its contents should be auto-selected.

To work around this you would have to subclass the edit control and handle the [WM_GETDLGCODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645425.aspx) message to alter the flags appropriately. First, derive a class from `CEdit`:

```
class CPersistentSelectionEdit : public CEdit {
public:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    afx_msg UINT OnGetDlgCode() {
        // Return default value, removing the DLGC_HASSETSEL flag
        return ( CEdit::OnGetDlgCode() & ~DLGC_HASSETSEL );
    }
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP( CPersistentSelectionEdit, CEdit )
    ON_WM_GETDLGCODE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Next subclass the actual control. There are a number of ways to do this. To keep things simple just declare a class member `m_Edit1` of type `CPersistentSelectionEdit` in your dialog class and add an appropriate entry in `DoDataExchange`:

```
// Subclass the edit control
DDX_Control( pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_Edit1 );
```

At this point you have an edit control that doesn't have its contents auto-selected when navigated to. You can control the selection whichever way you want.

Comment: If you use this method you don't lose the caret position every time you set focus to the text box, so I would prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there must be a code in your program to highlight the selection. Please find something like this:

```
CEdit* pEdit = ((CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1));
pEdit->SetFocus();
pEdit->SetSel(0, -1); // select everything
```

Simply comment the last two lines, instead of >SetSel(0). Your code is enabling and disabling which is meaningless to me.